# Why does Cabal, unlike GHC, not automatically enable GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving if I explicitly enabled DerivingStrategies?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, cabal, language-extension

From [the documentation](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_strategies.html#deriving-strategies) I'm inclined to think that if I enable the `DerivingStrategies` extension, I don't need to enable `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` or `DeriveAnyClass`, nor any other extension that I currently listed right before [§6.6.7.1](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_strategies.html#default-deriving-strategy), e.g. `DerivingVia`.

However, this toy example

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}

newtype MyNum = MyNum Int
 deriving stock (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
 deriving newtype (Num, Enum, Real, Integral)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ MyNum 0
```

compiles just fine via `ghc this-file.hs` (GHC 9.4.8), but it doesn't via `cabal build` (Cabal 3.10.2.1), because in the latter case, it is also required that I add

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
```

Any clue why is that?

---

The dummy `foo.cabal` file I'm using is

```
cabal-version:   3.8
name:            foo
version:         1.0

executable foo
    main-is:          main.hs
    build-depends:    base
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do need to enable the individual extensions. `DerivingStrategies` only gives you new syntax to specify which deriving strategy you want.

The reason that GHC doesn't require you to enable `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` is because it is part of the `GHC2021` language extension set and GHC uses the language extension set `GHC2021` by default.

Cabal determines the language extension set it uses via the `default-language` field of your components. In your example you have left it out (which is bad practice) and apparently Cabal still uses `Haskell2010` by default in that case. So, to fix this you can simply set the `default-language` field:

```
cabal-version:   3.8
name:            foo
version:         1.0

executable foo
    main-is:          main.hs
    build-depends:    base
    default-language: GHC2021
```

Comment: I had stripped `default-language: Haskell2010` when I asked the question :D